# How to make a custom Class file part of Xcode? (I.E. importable from any new project without having to copy the class)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

As the title says, I wanna be able to import a custom class of mine from any new project. So for example, if I have a class called  `LAView`, I wanna be able to type `#import "LAView.h"` from any new project without actually having to copy `LAView.h` and `LAView.m` into the project itself. Is that possible? :)

Comment: Create your own project template and include that class. That's one way.

Comment: You could also try creating a framework, but still you would have to include the framework in new projects but its just drag and drop and you can get all your classes. This would be the ideal way to go about it.

Comment: ^ And what do you mean by that exactly? Sorry, I've been going through the templates all day but IDK where I'm supposed to put the class.

Comment: @GoodSp33d Hmm okay, that'd probably be best. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a framework, copy the finished product into `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks` and `/Library/Frameworks/`

This way your framework will be visible and available in any Xcode project and you can access it like any other framework from the Xcode frameworks list.

NOTE: When you edit your framework you will have to copy the new version into both these locations again. You can automate this using BASH scripts run from the Terminal (if you do this be careful!).